# .NET Core data protection - where is it used?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, data-protection

I am using **.NET Core 3.1**. I have the following code snippet in `Startup.cs` inside `ConfigureServices`:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    
    services.AddDataProtection()
        .SetApplicationName("MyApplication")
        .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine("AppData", "Keys")));
    
    // ...
}
```

As far as I understand, this is only needed if I want to protect some input with `IDataProtectionProvider`, like so:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    readonly IDataProtectionProvider _rootProvider;
    public MyClass(IDataProtectionProvider rootProvider)
    {
        _rootProvider = rootProvider;
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        IDataProtector protector = provider.CreateProtector("Test123");
        string protectedPayload = protector.Protect("Hello world");
        Console.WriteLine($"Protect returned: {protectedPayload}");
    }
}
```

However, we are not using this functionality aynwhere in our application. Is it safe to remove `AddDataProtection` from `ConfigureServices`? Does any part of .NET Core application (TempData, AntiForgery tokens, ...) use it behind the scenes (so that Visual Studio doesn't find string `IDataProtectionProvider`)?

Comment: If you are not using it, then its not needed, its as simple as that. However you will need to assure yourself you aren't

Comment: Why did you *add* this in the first place? This isn't part of any template, someone added it to the project. We can't tell you why you or your team added this. You'll have to find whoever added it and ask them. Besides, Data Protection is used to protect any data, not just input. You may want to store some sensitive configuration settings, API keys, tokens etc. You may have to retrieve settings from a central storage and store them locally for example.

Comment: @TheGeneral The application works normally if I remove it. I just wanted to be extra sure that it is not used anywhere else behind the scenes. :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Is there any keyword that I should search for in order to determine if our application protects the data in any way? Can you protect the data without using `IDataProtectionProvider`?

Comment: TempData uses it, for instance. It's also used for anti-forgery tokens generated for form POST actions.

Comment: @MartinCostello Thank you for pointing it out. Is there any documentation about where **exactly** data protection is used?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything _specific_ - it's kinda of just a foundational component other things can use to protect data. I'm aware of these two specifically as I've had issues in the past with TempData and anti-forgery in a web farm where each instance would have different data protection keys and cause issues for users. The fix in that scenario is to configure data protection to store keys in a shared location, such as Azure Blob Storage or AWS S3. It's sort of like the .NET Core equivalent of .NET Framework `<machineKey>` in that regard.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know that only we can know an answer to that. This is very old code and there isn't any comment on why it was added. We just suspect that it isn't even needed and wanted to remove it.

Comment: Check the git history or a kind of JIRA ticket, or search for Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection in the project, if it does exist try removing it and test how the application will behave. 
Removing unused code is a good practice as it might be a potential security vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1), here's a sentence said:

> It cannot directly be used to protect or unprotect data. Instead, the
> consumer must get a reference to an IDataProtector by calling
> IDataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector(purpose)

hence based on this saying, it seems that data protection doesn't work as `_rootProvider` didn't be called in some place. And your another misgiving is some default setting or effect may work in some other places, you may refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/using-data-protection?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to see the common usage of data protection api.

And in my opinion, it's really hard to say it have no influence in your project as if by any chance we ignore some thing, that may lead to something unexpected. So if your app runs well now, why not just leave it there.